# how to return download file and continue execute another code in only controller laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Here is some code of my controller:

```
public function export()
{
    $this->getTemplate();
    $post=Post::find(1)->get();
    return redirect()->back()->with($post);
}

public function getTemplate()
{
    return Storage::download('public\template\note.docx');
}
```

but when i run this controller, it called `getTemplate` function but it dont retunt file, and other code in export function still continue

Comment: correct me if i'm wrong, but i believe you can't. because headers are already sent that you are  supposed to be "downloading" a file.

Comment: what does this mean @Joe

Comment: when you sent the `Storage::download(...)` response, you are telling the browser that it should download a file. therefore, you cannot redirect the user anymore.

Comment: so, Is there any other way to solve it?

Answer (score -1):

I would return the url and then use download.js to download the file on load or button press what ever you like

Here is an example:

http://pagedemos.com/sxks39b72aqb/7

hope this helps

**Update**

If you change your code to something like this:

```
public function export() {

    $url = $this->getTemplate();
    $post=Post::find(1);
    return redirect()->back()->with([$post, $url]);

}

public function getTemplate() {

    return Storage::url('public\template\note.docx');

}
```

and add something like below to your view:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/downloadjs/1.4.8/download.min.js"></script>

$(document).ready(function() {

    $.ajax({
        url: "{{ $url }}",
        success: download.bind(true, "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document", "note.docx")
    })

});
```

This will allow you to return the post page and trigger the download

Comment: I think that is also a suggestion for me, but it is not what i want

Comment: @nguyễnmạnh I have update my answer with more detail. If this does not solve your problem then you will need to give us more info.

Comment: it mean i must use ajax, right! Is there any other way to solve it?

Comment: Sorry @nguyễnmạnh Not that I know of!

Comment: I appreciate your answer. But I will find another solution that is not ajax